# What is the best solution for filling limited variables in PHP

Tags: php, calculus

Let's say I have 3 variables

```
$a;
$b;

$c = 30;
```

What I wish to do here is that I have to divide `$c` and put it in the first 2 variables which can be easily done by doing.

```
$a = $c / 2;
$b = $c / 2;
```

However what if in `$b` there is a maximum value limit of 10 and $a is limitless. 
In this case the values have to be.

```
$a = 20;
$b = 10;
```

What would be the best solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If B has a limit, then you would need to calculate B first. Then work out the difference between C & B and set A as the answer.

```
<?php

$a;
$b;

$c = 100;


$b = min(10, $c / 2);
$a = ($c - $b);

echo "A: " . $a;
echo "B: " . $b;
?>
```

Comment: This seems like the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [min](http://php.net/min)

```
$a = $c / 2;
$b = min(10, $c / 2);
```

Comment: Sorry edited it so that `$c` is limitless forgot to put it in.

Comment: the jist is you want to do your math, then either use `max` and/or `min` to bound your value.

Comment: This wont work. You would get `$a = 15` and `$b = 10`